# 'std::filesystem' has not been declared after including <experimental/filesystem>

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have checked a lot of issues about the link of filesystem under c++17 and I still cannot make the link successfully. My `main.cpp` file is as the following.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string imageDirectory = "./image";;
    std::vector<std::string> imagePath;

    for (const auto& entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(imageDirectory))
    {
        imagePath.push_back(entry.path());
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is as the following.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(visual_hull LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_library(dataIO
        STATIC
            dataIO.hpp
            dataIO.cpp)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)

target_link_libraries(dataIO ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(visual_hull main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(visual_hull PUBLIC dataIO
                                         stdc++fs)
```

The error is as the following.

```
/home/SENSETIME/zhangshunkang/Downloads/programming/c++/visual_hull/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/SENSETIME/zhangshunkang/Downloads/programming/c++/visual_hull/main.cpp:15:31: error: ‘std::filesystem’ has not been declared
  for (const auto& entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(imageDirectory))
                               ^
CMakeFiles/visual_hull.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/visual_hull.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/visual_hull.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/visual_hull.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/visual_hull.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: In C++17 it should be `#include <filesystem>`  and if you are using `clang++` or `g++` add `-lstdc++fs` when compiling.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I have tried it and I got the same error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo What about the cmake link?

Comment: @Sean That's not a linker error. That's a compiler error.

Comment: You are including `experimental/filesystem` but using `std::filesystem`. Change the include to `#include <filesystem>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I just include the filesystem, I will get the error that filesystem: No such file or directory.

Comment: @Sean then it appears that your standard library implementation may be too old to support C++17; or just broken.

Comment: Regarding the title: CMake is not a linker, so it can't link anything by design. The file in question is a header file, and those being just plain text don't get linked, they get included by a preprocessor.

Comment: With g++, using #include <filesystem> and adding "-std=c++17" when compiling fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`. `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and the entire namespace `std::filesystem` are declared in the header `<filesystem>`.

You haven't included the header `<filesystem>`. Instead, you've included `<experimental/filesystem>`. This header does not declare `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`. Instead, it declares `std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator`.

You can consistently use either the standard filesystem library, or the experimental filesystem library from the technical specification, but you must not mix them together. If you're targeting C++17, then you should use `<filesystem>`.

> I will get the error that filesystem: No such file or directory

The ideal solution is to upgrade your compiler to a version that has non-experimental support for C++17. Otherwise use the experimental TS or Boost.

Answer (score 14):

It seems your C++17 compiler doesn't include the standard `filesystem` header. One possible way to get around that:

```
#ifndef __has_include
  static_assert(false, "__has_include not supported");
#else
#  if __cplusplus >= 201703L && __has_include(<filesystem>)
#    include <filesystem>
     namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#  elif __has_include(<experimental/filesystem>)
#    include <experimental/filesystem>
     namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#  elif __has_include(<boost/filesystem.hpp>)
#    include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
     namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
#  endif
#endif
```

Then use `fs::` instead of `std::filesystem::` everywhere.

Checking `__cplusplus >= 201703L` is just an extra precaution if you want to use `filesystem` when using C++11/14. In those cases, `__has_include(<filesystem>)` may be `true` but including it will not define the `std::filesystem` namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Cpp 17 does not understand the standard library.
In Cmake.txt add:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lstdc++fs -std=c++17")
```