# Where to put header files in order to make them accessible for all .cpp programs?

Tags: c++, include, header-files

[There's a "filesystem" library in my laptop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3HT8.png)
When I compile the code [I get an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA8uD.png). I tried putting *-lstdc++fs* in the compile command, but it didn't work. It should, according to [GCC manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qspr.png). What do I do? I think I'm lost.

My **GCC** version is *6.3.0*.

edit: <experimental/filesystem> also isn't working.

```
 Directory of C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\experimental

12.04.2021  19:16    <DIR>          .
12.04.2021  19:16    <DIR>          ..
29.05.2017  23:00             4 903 algorithm
29.05.2017  23:00            14 716 any
29.05.2017  23:00             3 187 array
12.04.2021  19:16    <DIR>          bits
29.05.2017  23:00             1 976 chrono
29.05.2017  23:00             2 356 deque
29.05.2017  23:00             2 412 forward_list
29.05.2017  23:00            14 093 functional    
29.05.2017  23:00             3 594 iterator
29.05.2017  23:00             2 323 list
29.05.2017  23:00             2 667 map
29.05.2017  23:00             6 063 memory
29.05.2017  23:00            11 928 memory_resource
29.05.2017  23:00             3 114 numeric
29.05.2017  23:00            28 890 optional
29.05.2017  23:00            15 285 propagate_const
29.05.2017  23:00             2 361 random
29.05.2017  23:00             2 455 ratio
29.05.2017  23:00             2 163 regex
29.05.2017  23:00             2 541 set
29.05.2017  23:00             2 927 string
29.05.2017  23:00            21 233 string_view
29.05.2017  23:00             2 062 system_error
29.05.2017  23:00             2 524 tuple
29.05.2017  23:00            11 057 type_traits
29.05.2017  23:00             2 913 unordered_map
29.05.2017  23:00             2 796 unordered_set
29.05.2017  23:00             1 633 utility
29.05.2017  23:00             2 428 vector
              28 File(s)        176 600 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  282 055 958 528 bytes free
```

Comment: Instead of putting links to pictures in your question, please read this from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: Try `gcc -xc++ -E -v -` for the standard include path, although I do not recommend this approach. Write your own local library and manually add the include path in your compiler arguments.

Comment: Did you also use `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++1z` when compiling?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475023/7582247) help?

Comment: See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or some newer C++ standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use GCC 6 you not only need add -lstdc++fs, but include *<**experimental**/filesystem>*:

```sh
g++ file.cpp -lstdc++fs
```

You also need to remember that you're using experimental library, so you need to use experimental namespace as well:

```cpp
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

If you don't want to be forced to use *experimental* in header path you need to update GCC to version 8 or higher and use

Comment: the problem is, there's no filesystem folder in the <experimental> library. compiler throws out errors when i use either <experimental/filesystem> or <filesystem>. should i use boost, then?

Comment: Pass here your compilation command please

Comment: g++ pixel.cpp -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs

Comment: I played with GCC and updated my answer. Now your problem should be solved.