# Using std::experimental::filesystem with g++ 9.3.0

Tags: c++, g++

I'm using VS2015 as my main developing tool and to use `std::filesystem` there I need to write something like this:

`namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;`

Now I need to compile this code using g++ 9.3.0 and, of course, get an error about "experimental" part. Is there a way to keep this oldy thing in my code and compile it with modern g++?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475023/7582247) help a bit?

Comment: Unfourtannetelly, it looks like VS2015 doesn't support `__has_include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the **version of C++ standard** in combination with a pre-processor directive to distinguish between them as it the filesystem library has been [officially introduced in C++17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem?view=msvc-160)

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
  #include <filesystem>
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#else
  #include <experimental/filesystem>
  namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#endif
```

In case this occurs to you with another library in C++17 you can use [__has_include](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

```
#if __has_include(<some_lib>)
  #include <some_lib>
  namespace sl = std::some_lib;
#else
  #include <experimental/some_lib>
  namespace sl = std::experimental::some_lib;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` for g++. If you need to compile the same code in both compilers, use `#if` to differentiate between them.

Comment: `#if` it's obvious solution but what should be the condition to do it automatically depending on compiler version?