"filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Permission denied" on 0777 directory
My code looks like this:
auto const dir = std::filesystem::path(...);
std::error_code ec (0, std::generic_category());
try {
    for (auto const& inner_entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(dir, std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink, ec)) {
        std::cout << "Trying to set " << inner_entry.path().c_str() << "to 0666\n";
        try {
            // Code setting permissions on file to 0666
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "Cannot set " << inner_entry.path().c_str() << "to 0666\n";
        }
    }
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "Cannot for loop with: " << e.what() << ", " << ec.message();
}

My files look like:
dir/tmp/data1/
    dir1/
    dir2/
    file1
    file2

With the following stat outputs:
  File: /dir
  Size: 1024            Blocks: 2          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 706h/1798d      Inode: 1897        Links: 3
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  default)   Gid: (  default)

  File: /dir/tmp/
  Size: 1024            Blocks: 2          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 706h/1798d      Inode: 1899        Links: 3
Access: (0666/drw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (  default)   Gid: (  default)

  File: /dir/tmp/data1
  Size: 1024            Blocks: 2          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 706h/1798d      Inode: 1900        Links: 6
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  default)   Gid: (  default)


My output looks like:
Trying to set dir/ to 0666
Trying to set dir/tmp/ to 0666
Cannot for loop with: filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Permission denied, Success

Issue:

It looks like it is able to recurse into /dir/ and /dir/tmp/ but not dir/tmp/data1 for some reason despite them all have the same uid/gid and open file permissions (0777/0666)

Notes:

I'm not sure if I passed in the std::error_code ec in correctly to std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator since ec.message() is printing out Success
The whole filesystem (from /) is mounted from somewhere else but I don't think it has anything to do with this since /dir/ and /dir/tmp/ have no issues?


Is shelling out to chmod -R a+rwX an option for you? That limits you to POSIX platforms, but would certainly be simpler to implement.

A directory with mode 0666 is an unusual thing. It has the read and write bits set, but not the execute bit. On a directory, the execute bit actually means "search permission", which basically allows you to access files and subdirectories inside it by name.
Try it:
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ chmod 0666 foo
$ ls -l foo
ls: cannot access 'foo/bar': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bar
$ cat foo/bar
cat: foo/bar: Permission denied

I'm not sure this fully explains the behaviour you're seeing, because changing permissions during recursive_directory_iterator execution probably does not have well defined behaviour.
TL;DR: On directories, use mode 0777 for full, unrestricted access. (And unless you're in a Docker container or other kind of sandbox, you'll probably want 0755 or 0700 instead, otherwise any other user has full access too.)

Thanks for your answer! It worked after setting them to 0777 instead. From your comment that it is not well defined behaviour, is there a proper way to change the permissions of all the items within a directory?

From cppreference: "The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry is visited only once." That means it could try to visit subdirectories before parents, and the parent might not be accessible yet. To make it bulletproof, you might have to write your own recursive iteration based on directory_iterator instead.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249234/how-to-perform-chmod-recursively

Thanks for the explanation and link to the reference!
